# Write bash script for memcached command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, memcached

I want to delete a key-value in memcached every 60 seconds.
My command for deleting:

```
{ delete my-key-value; sleep 1; } | telnet 10.10.10.10 11211
```

Console's output: Cannot find command delete.
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message says it all - `delete` is not a command. `sleep 1` only sleeps for approximately 1 second, 60 would be what you're looking for. I believe your also trying to send commands to a server by piping them to a `telnet` command, which I don't think is the correct way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: did you mean, `while true; do echo "delete my-key-value"; sleep 60; done | telnet 10.10.10.10 11211` Or maybe, `while true; do echo "delete my-key-value" | telnet 10.10.10.10 11211; sleep 60; done`

Comment: Full bash script like that:

Answer (score 2):

@anishsane. Thanks for your help!

Base on comment of anishsane. I change delete command to:

```
{ echo "delete my-key-value"; sleep 1; } | telnet 10.10.10.10 11211
```

It work.